# how to have a user-inputed string check against a list of words

Tags: javascript, html

So, I'm trying to create a website in which a user of the website would input a string into a box and it would check the string against a list of words and phrases and if a word or phrase in the string matches a word in the list of words or phrases it would give a response. Is this possible to do through html or does it require JS using variables or something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check what does [includes()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp) do. You can check if the string contains another string (or you can do it in a loop for array of strings)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do it with [almost no JS](https://jsfiddle.net/2mun1pr8/), but it will be easier to maintain and have better functionality using JS:

```js
var resultsDiv = document.getElementById('results'),
    // This dictionary contains normalized keys (no uppercase, no punctuation)
    dictionary = {
      "hello": "<b>Hello</b> my friend!",
      "hell no": "<b>Hell, no</b>!",
      "bye": "<b>Bye</b>, sad to see you go...",
      "goodbye": "<b>Goodbye</b>, sad to see you go...",
      "good afternoon": "<b>Good afternoon</b>, my friend!"
    };

// When the user inputs a string, execute the function
document.getElementById('search-input').addEventListener('input', findMatches);

function findMatches() {
  // Reset the results
  resultsDiv.innerHTML = "";
  var searchStr = this.value   // Normalize the search string:
    .toLowerCase()             // Make the search case insensitive
    .replace(/[^a-z0-9]/, ' ') // Replace all non alphanumeric characters with spaces
    .replace(/\s+/, ' ')       // Replace multiple spaces with just one
    .trim();                   // Trim spaces at the begining and end
  if (searchStr.length > 0) {
    // Get all the keys from the dictionary
    var results = Object.keys(dictionary)
                        // Filter those that match the query
                        .filter(function(key) { return key.indexOf(searchStr) > -1; })
                        // Produce HTML for each of them
                        .map(function(key) {
                          return '<div class="result">' + dictionary[key] + '</div>';
                        })
                        // Join this Array into a String
                        .join('');
    // Output that HTML
    resultsDiv.innerHTML = results;
  }
}
```

```css
.result {
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  padding: .5em;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Type "hello", "bye", "good"...:</p>
<input id="search-input" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off"/>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: what about someone entering a string and if a single word in that script matches a set list of words it outputs something and if none of the words match it outputs a different thing